# PHP SOAP request with wsdl not working, it gives me an error "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'phoneNumber' property"

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wsdl, soap-client

I need help to send request data to SOAP API using wsdl in PHP. I have installed soapclient extension for php and it is working fine. Here is the script :

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, array('username' => USER_NAME, 'password'  => PASSWORD,'trace'=>'1','exception'=>0));
$method = "templateSMS";

$xmlr = new SimpleXMLElement("<Sms></Sms>");
$xmlr->addChild("phoneNumber",PHONE_NUMBER);
$xmlr->addChild('message', 'Hi how are you');
$xmlr->addChild('unicodeMessage', 0);
$xmlr->addChild('sms_type_id', 1);
$xmlr->addChild('senderId', SENDER_ID);
$xmlr->addChild('notify', 0);
$xmlr->addChild('priority', 1);
$xmlr->addChild('vbApp', 'SoapRequest');
$xmlr->addChild('vbIdTime', time());
$params = new stdClass();
$params->xml = $xmlr->asXML();
try {    
   $data = $client->$method($params);
   var_dump($data);
}catch (SoapFault $e) {    
   echo "<pre> Exceptions Break  :";
     print_r($e);
   echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

When I run above code in browser it gives me an error "**SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'phoneNumber' property**"

Here is the error log, might be more helpfull to fix my issue :

```
 Exceptions Break  :SoapFault Object
(
[message:protected] => SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'phoneNumber' property
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\soapDemo\opt3.php
[line:protected] => 18
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\soapDemo\opt3.php
                [line] => 18
                [function] => __call
                [class] => SoapClient
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => templateSMS
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [xml] => 
    Hi how are you0101SoapRequest1480835353

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\soapDemo\opt3.php
                [line] => 18
                [function] => templateSMS
                [class] => SoapClient
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [xml] => 
      Hi how are you0101SoapRequest1480835353

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[previous:Exception:private] => 
[faultstring] => SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'phoneNumber' property
[faultcode] => Client
[faultcodens] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
)
```

Support team gives me an sample xml code to pass request format and here is the sample xml request format, Request should be same as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:templateSMS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="urn:ElbaridTNS" xmlns:ns3="namespace" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<ns3:AuthHeader>
<username>username </username>
<password>password</password>
</ns3:AuthHeader>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:templateSMS>
<Sms xsi:type="ns2:Sms"><phoneNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxxxx</phoneNumber>
<message xsi:type="xsd:string">test SMS </message>
<unicodeMessage xsi:type="xsd:string">test SMS</unicodeMessage>
<sms_type_id xsi:type="xsd:string">1</sms_type_id>
<notify xsi:type="xsd:string">0</notify>
<senderId xsi:type="xsd:string">SenderId</senderId>
<priority xsi:type="xsd:string">2</priority>
<vbApp xsi:type="xsd:string">SoapRequest</vbApp>
<vbIdTime xsi:type="xsd:string">20161130101112</vbIdTime>
<destinationPort xsi:type="xsd:string">-1</destinationPort></Sms>
</ns1:templateSMS>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:templateSMS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:templateSMSResponse>
<templateSMSResponse xsi:type="xsd:string">0#!#200#!#http://198.101.210.203/Soap/service/elbarid|http://212.98.137.180/Soap/service/elbarid#!#SenderId </templateSMSResponse>
</ns1:templateSMSResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can anyone help me to fix my issue? I also try with CURL but I got same error respond.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need pass array as parameter.

```
$params = array('Sms'=>array('phoneNumber'=>'123456879','message'=>'test')); //add all params. in Sms array.
```

And then call method

```
$data = $client->$method($params);
```

Comment: Thanks for response.... 
But still I am getting same error : SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'phoneNumber' property